# alert() sometimes causes an error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I used to use `alert()` for debugging, when I code some lines in JavaScript/jQuery (I know, it is bad style). I now see a strange behaviour in Google Chrome.

**HTML**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="my_script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Test</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**my_script.js**

This is really simple.

```
    alert("hello world");
```

**Error**

When I load the page it normally works fine, but when I reload the page *sometimes* the following error occurs in Google Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined   extensions::messaging:184

By testing it several times I found that

- the `alert()` window appears as expected
- the error occurs not every time but sometimes
- the error occurs (when it occurs) **after** closing the `alert()` window
- the error seems not to occur if I wait to close the `alert()` window, or between two reloads

The error message points to this code-snippet:

```
  // In case the extension never invokes the responseCallback, and also
  // doesn't keep a reference to it, we need to clean up the port. Do
  // so by attaching to the garbage collection of the responseCallback
  // using some native hackery.
  messagingNatives.BindToGC(responseCallback, function() {
    if (port) {
      privates(port).impl.destroy_();
      port = null;
    }
  });
```

But I even couldn't figure out which file is exactly affected and in which folder it is placed.

Google just found one another description of obviously the same error:
https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/anyone-else-getting-error-cannot-read-property-impl-of-undefined

The author of this page supposes that the fact, the error occurs only sometimes, points to a problem with an asynchronous process, which is not finished sometimes one reloads the page.

I solved my debugging tasks by switching to the use of `console.log()`. But I'm quite interested what error exactly occurs and how I could avoid it to return to my bad style of debugging by using the `alert()` function.

Comment: sounds like a chrome bug. report it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey (: I found a possible explanation for your question in this forum (https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/anyone-else-getting-error-cannot-read-property-impl-of-undefined). I quote : 'undefined is being returned prior to accessing the property impl. Since it's occurring intermittently, that suggests to me that privates(port) is an asynchronous operation - which allows other code to continue executing - sometimes privates will finish before accessing the property impl, sometimes it won't.' End quote. Even though it.s just a speculation I find it rational

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I already found that page (see my question) and it doesn't answer how to avoid the error.

Comment: What if instead of making the alert in a separate javascript file, you define it, for example, on body load? <body onload='alert('hello world'); i'm guessing that the alert request would happen only after body finish loading..